# Как получить доступ из одной папки в другую?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylance

У меня есть проект, состоящий, допустим, из двух папок:

```
first
    -> init.py
    -> some_module.py
second
    -> init.py
    -> different_module.py
main.py
```

Допустим, я хочу вызвать different_module.py в some_module.py, однако простой import хоть и работает, однако подсвечивается красным в vs code с ошибкой

```
Import "second.different_module.py" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
```

Почему и как это решить?

Comment: По тексту ошибки похоже, что вы импортируете как `import second.different_module.py`, нужно импортировать по имени модуля без расширения: `import second.different_module`

Answer (score 0):

```
from second import different_module
```

Попробуйте так, единственое, если надо импортировать какой-то класс из `different_module.py`, то просто пишите имя класса.

Comment: Верно говорите, из-за невнимательности не удалил, просто скопировал с вопроса и вставил, забыл удалить(

Comment: Собственно, у меня так и было, просто немного опечатался в вопросе с ".py", который отсутствует и в моём коде, и в ошибке. 

Проблема именно в доступе из одной папки в другую и она чисто связанная с pylance. Она высвечивается(притом именно в vs code, сама же программа при выполнении вполне нормально всё импортирует) даже при попытки из _some_module_ импортировать весь _second_